# Application stops decrypting data with MachineKey.Unprotect

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, encryption

I've been using machinekey.protect and machinekey.unprotect to encrypt data, but after an unspecified time (say 2 weeks) the application can no longer decrypt the data (it throws a cryptographic error). I haven't specified the MachineKey attribute in web.config so I was planning to do that through the IIS interface.

The encrypted data is read, inserted and updated via at least two sites in the same overall IIS server instance, so my question is: if I generate machine keys in IIS, should the keys be the same across all sites in IIS? I'm assuming that if I generate a unique key for each application it won't decrypt across all sites, is this correct? And would manually generating the keys solve the initial decryption problem?

Comment: yes, the keys need to the be same across all sites if they need to decrypt across all the sites.

Comment: If I go into IIS Manager and select the server instance on the left, I can generate and apply a machine key at that level, and specify that it should not be unique for each site. However this doesn't seem to do much. For each site should I copy and paste the keys generated at the top level, or can I create keys at the site level, and then copy and paste those into the other sites? Would that work?